# Pairing Samsung Gear S2 with iBeacon

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-gear-s2

I would like to make a connection between my Gear S2 and iBeacon directly through the BLE Network. I have seen there are Bluetooth API available in the SDK from Tizen.But i havent went throught it in detail. I would just like to know if this idea is possible or have anyone have successfully made this happen.

There is a master mode in he watch to scan for BT_Headset. can i modify this application to achieve my goal?

Thank you.

Comment: To help you find an answer, understand that iBeacon does not actually "pair" with a Bluetooth device or even establish a connection.  Beacons send BLE advertisements.  Si all the Tizen device needs to do is scan for Bluetooth devices and pass on the raw packet bytes of the scan results to your code. Big you can do this, you can make it detect and decode iBeacon transmissions.

Comment: I agree with davidyoung, you have to make your Tizen app listen to the advertisements, you cannot pair like normal Bluetooth connections.

Comment: question was also asked on tizen boards :
https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/how-can-we-communicate-tizen-device-ibeacon-device#comment-22488

Answer (score 0):

In a native service app, I have been able to use `bt_adapter_le_start_scan` and parse the bytes provided in `adv_data` in the `bt_adapter_le_device_scan_result_info_s` parameter provided in the scan callback to determine the presence of an iBeacon device.

Unfortunately, at this time Tizen is only providing "connectable" devices in the BLE scan callback.  In my situation, this means that the beacon has been put into configurable mode (in order to configure the broadcast iBeacon values, power, advertising interval).  And configurable mode times out after a certain (short) amount of time. Therefore, iBeacon detection on Tizen is currently infeasible for my purposes.

Comment: This is unfortunate.  It may not help, but it is certainly possible to build beacons that set the connectable flag in the bluetooth advertisement.  (The BLE devices don't actually have to allow connections just because they say they are connectable.)  While this might work, clearly this would be a non-standard approach, and wouldn't work with off-the-shelf beacons.